# How to diagnose an iOS crash report(SIGSEGV) from Crittercism

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segmentation-fault

Below is the crash report I received from Crittercism, where the crash name is given as SIGSEGV and reason is SEGV_MAPERR.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000196363bd0 objc_msgSend + 12
1   UIKit 0x00000001893df9bc -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 68
2   UIKit 0x000000018911cb9c -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 496
3   UIKit 0x00000001891d2880 -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 296
4   UIKit 0x00000001893e0634 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 860
5   UIKit 0x00000001891d8b64 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 396
6   UIKit 0x00000001891d898c -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 40
7   UIKit 0x00000001890fda08 -[UIView dealloc] + 436
8   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000196369724 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop() + 560
9   CoreFoundation 0x0000000184564d14 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
10 CoreFoundation 0x00000001846395f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1496
11 CoreFoundation 0x0000000184564f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
12 GraphicsServices 0x000000018dfbf6fc GSEventRunModal + 164
13 UIKit 0x0000000189166d94 UIApplicationMain + 1484
14 MyApplication 0x000000010004bd80 main (main.m:7) 
15 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001969faa08 start + 0
```

Though the output is already symbolicated, it is still rather difficult to figure out what and where actually the problem is.

Originally I thought I continued calling the delegate or datasource of my tableView even after they were gone so I added following to all view controllers whenever the tableview's delegate was used.  However, this didn't resolve the crash.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    if (self.tableView) {
        self.tableView.delegate = nil;
        self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
    }
}
```

I also tried turning on the "Enable Zombie Objects" option in XCode, but currently I am not able to reproduce this locally.

This crash is occurring mostly on iPhone 5s/6(about 45% each) with iOS versions from 8.0 to the latest 8.4.1. The application is using ARC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the Exception Breakpoint to see exactly where the crash is occurring? (Sorry if thats too obvious) Other than that, I noticed that the UIScrollView is being removed from the superview and then _notifyDidScroll is being called just before the crash.  Is the UIScrollView object still valid in the context?  What action precedes the crash?  Is it reproducible?

Comment: Since the crash happen randomly on client side (and i did not know exactly where), it is a bit hard to use exception breakpoint in such case.  I am investigating the UIScrollView and have yet to find anything helpful though.

Comment: If the crash is random, and adding an exception breakpoint doesn't pinpoint the source, you may have a memory leak.  Have you tried running the app through Instruments to look at the performance?

Comment: Yes I did that several times and hadn't found memory leaks yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
You'd need to clear NavigationController's delegate.
Because in iOS 8 to iOS 8.3 UINavigationController's delegate is `retain` not `weak`
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html
[image]

Also, clearing that delegate in `dealloc` doesn't help. Delegate method will called before `dealloc`. Then crash happened.

Put that in viewDidDisappear.